# Weird Windows 'cleanmgr' result

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cleaning

I just ran `cleanmgr` in my windows 7 and I've got a seriously weird result. 
It says my TEMP folder is 352 GB. But my HDD is only 300 GB. I have 2 OS on it (Windows 7 and a Linux)

Is is virus related, bug, ...what should I do ?

Should I click to clean those 352 GB ?

Comment: Yes;You should.

Comment: Not sure why it shows such large space as being occupied by TEMP. But it's a good idea to read this first. [Serious Disk Cleanup Problem in Windows caused by Broken Registration](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/serious-disk-cleanup-problem-caused-by-broken-registration/). This is the registry key you want to check in this case: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Files

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that many "files" listed in the WinSxS, and perhaps other folders, are [actually hard links, and there may be multiple links to one file, with size of each included in the sum.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bccb5f78-ce86-4be2-873a-f36544c7a8c9/winsxs-folder-size-increased-to-60-gb-windows-server-2008needs-resolution?forum=winservergen) Apparently MS has yet to update Explorer to show the true size of its contents.

It is safe to remove files using Windows Disk Cleanup. After the initial pause, you then need to click *Clean up system files*. If you are willing to forego being able to revert to the state before updates were installed, [you casn use the *dism* utility to remove yet more files.](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/clean-winsxs-folder-to-save-space)